# Cyclic imports and subclasses in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, import

Relatively new to Python here. I was getting errors for cyclic imports, so I changed all my import statements to `import *module name*`

I want to do something like this (below would be module2):

```
import module1

class Subclass(Superclass)
    # some code
```

where Superclass is defined in modeule1 and Subclass inherits from Superclass.

I am getting the error that Superclass is not defined. I've tried with `class Subclass(module1.Superclass)` as well, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of the following:

```
import module1

class Subclass(module1.Superclass):
    pass
    #some code
```

Or:

```
from module1 import Superclass

class Subclass(Superclass):
    pass
    #some code
```

Python needs to either know 1) the namespace through which it can access the class or 2) explicitly import the class.

For clarity, `module1` could look like the following:

```
class Superclass:
    pass
    #some code
```

**EXAMPLE**

For `module1.py`:

```
class Superclass:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def a(self):
        print('a')

    def b(self):
        print('b')
```

And then `module2.py`:

```
from module1 import Superclass

class Subclass(Superclass):
    pass

x = Subclass().a()
```

Running `module2.py` will return:

```
a
```

Comment: How have you defined `module1`?

Comment: It has some functions, and then a class `class Superclass:` with some more functions inside that class. My module2 has a the subclass class, one function, and another class.

Comment: Please update you question with a minimal verifiable example and all of the code that reproduces your issue.